# Error when performing migration on heroku: django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration

I'm unable to perform `syncdb` on my herokuapp upon intitial deployment, and keep running into the following error:

```
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration custompusher.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'push_notifications', u'0002_auto_20150629_1438')
```

`makemigrations` and `migrate` result in the same error btw. 
my app itself is quite basic. E.g. models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from push_notifications.models import GCMDevice
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
class DeviceObj(GCMDevice):
     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('success')
```

Note that push_notifications is a [3rd party library](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications/) that has its own migrations. Also note that the set up works fine locally, setting up on Heroku is the issue.